# How to access caller element inside callback function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jquery-ui button `test-button` that has a **data attribute**.
That button calls a custom widget `customWidget` that has a callback function `fnSaveCallback`.

```
$(".test-button").button({
    icons: {
        primary: 'icon-test icon-mixed icon-custom'
    },
    text: false 
}).customWidget({
    id: "custom-widget",
    title: "My custom widget",
    fnSaveCallback: function() {
        // Need to get the data-test attribute from the "test-button" 
    }
});
```

I'm having problems trying to access the the `test-button` in order to get the value of the data-attribute from the callback function.
Any idea how can i do that? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried `this`?

Comment: `this` inside the callback will not give me access to the button element but to the customWidget. Thanks for your time ;)

Comment: you can declare a variable outside of the callback `var test_button = $("#test-button")` and then you can access the element using the variable from within the callback.

Comment: I have more than one button with the class `test-button`, so that var gives me always the first button...

Comment: Where did you get this widget from?

Comment: The only other thing I can suggest is to patch the customWidget to expose the parent element and then you can access it via a property from `this`

Comment: It's a customWidget, created by me. But the idea is also not to change the widget...

Comment: If you wrote it yourself it's easy to expose the `target` when the callback is called.

Comment: I don't think you'll find an easy way - if any - to access the `target` without changing the widget code, I'm afraid.

Comment: Ok... Actually the customWidget calls a dialog inside and returns it in the callback function. Can i get the button from there?

Comment: You can return an anonymous object in the callback containing everything you need in its properties. Somewhere in that piece of code `this` would refer to the clicked `button`.

Comment: The idea is not to change the customWidget. But thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

I've found an easy way to handle this adding a class on the click event.

```
  $(".test-button").button({
        icons: {
            primary: 'icon-test icon-mixed icon-custom'
        },
        text: false 
  }).click(function() {
        // remove opener class from other test-buttons
        $(.test-button.opener).removeClass("opener");
        // add opener class to the clicked button
        $(this).addClass("opener");
  }.customWidget({
        id: "custom-widget",
        title: "My custom widget",
        fnSaveCallback: function() {
            // Get the data-test attribute from the "test-button"
            $(".test-button.opener").data("test");
        }
  });
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to have a reference of the element somewhere.

```
const test_button = document.getElementById('test-button');
```

and then in fvSaveCallback:

```
fnSaveCallback: function() {
    // Need to get the data-test attribute from the "test-button" 
    console.log(test_button.dataset.test);
}
```

EDIT: After your edit, as far as I understand you are trying to apply that method to all `.test-button` buttons.
You should only need to get a list of nodes, and iterate through it :)

```
const test_buttons = document.getElementsByClassName('test-button')
;

for (let i = 0; i < test_buttons.length; i++)
{ const button = test_buttons[i]; //This is the button
  // Do with 'button' whatever you want here.
  console.log(button.dataset.some_data);
}
```

Comment: So basically you're suggesting the OP create a `const` for every single `button` that's in the page?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake... The `test-button` is not an `id`, it's a class and there are many buttons with that class and without an `id`...

Comment: He is not specifying the full problem.

Comment: @DavidR You need to apply that to all button's of .test-button class?

Comment: Yes, i need. And for all the buttons the data attribute will be different..

Comment: How in your loop you identify which `button` has been clicked? It's not very clear...

Comment: Well, i've edited my answer... If you don't modify any of your existent functions to hold and pass some reference to the button, you will need to create an array of the buttons you wish to modify, an iterate through it doing your work.

Comment: Well, if you want to identify a button, you will need to put an ID. And the guy just wrote about a class name... also, i'm not making the whole code. If you want to know the target of an event, just access to the event.target property passed to an event listener.

Comment: Your answer doesn't address the problem in the question.

Comment: Why my answer doesn't address your problem? if you explain why, i can improve it. I may be misunderstanding something; english is not my first language.